# 16 inch MacBook Pro kernel panic when connected to LG ultrafine display

Tags: thunderbolt, kernel-panic, thunderbolt-display

I recently purchased a used LG Ultrafine 24MD4KL-B monitor on eBay. I also got Apple's thunderbolt 3 USB-c cable. The monitor charges my laptop, so I know it has power, but the display itself will not turn on. Strangely, the monitor works fine with my iPad Pro connected, so I know that the display works. Edit: I have tried all four ports on my Macbook as well as another 15 inch Macbook Pro and a Dell laptop, all of which did not work. I have tried restarting and resetting the SMC to no avail. When putting the MacBook to sleep, with the monitor plugged in, and waking it up I was able to get the following kernel panic:

```
panic(cpu 0 caller 0xffffff8006a9097c): Sleep transition timed out after 180 seconds while entering darkwake on way to sleep. Suspected bundle: com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily. Thread 0x26e.
Backtracing specified thread
Backtrace (CPU 0), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff81f7cf3900 : 0xffffff8006441868 
0xffffff9206a93c80 : 0xffffff800633c4d1 
0xffffff9206a93cf0 : 0xffffff800633ad0f 
0xffffff9206a93d40 : 0xffffff800632b8d0 
0xffffff9206a93d80 : 0xffffff8006a2bbec 
0xffffff9206a93dc0 : 0xffffff8006a2d0cb 
0xffffff9206a93df0 : 0xffffff7f8713e277 
0xffffff9206a93e10 : 0xffffff7f8713deab 
0xffffff9206a93e30 : 0xffffff8006a137e4 
0xffffff9206a93ea0 : 0xffffff8006a135ea 
0xffffff9206a93ec0 : 0xffffff800635c605 
0xffffff9206a93f40 : 0xffffff800635c131 
0xffffff9206a93fa0 : 0xffffff80062c013e 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily(7.6.1)[8BAB933D-3D4A-3CBA-B931-5358826BC215]@0xffffff7f8713c000->0xffffff7f8722ffff
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleSMC(3.1.9)[AB612149-B321-3B95-8741-B99E79274FCD]@0xffffff7f86da9000

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: kernel_task
Boot args: chunklist-security-epoch=0 -chunklist-no-rev2-dev

Mac OS version:
19G2021

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 19.6.0: Thu Jun 18 20:49:00 PDT 2020; root:xnu-6153.141.1~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 1D3A0F3D-D908-397B-BD16-8F48C0823A2E
Kernel slide:     0x0000000006000000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8006200000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff8006100000
System model name: MacBookPro16,1 (Mac-E1008331FDC96864)
System shutdown begun: NO

System uptime in nanoseconds: 223335921325
last loaded kext at 52609271958: >!AThunderboltPCIUpAdapter 2.5.4 (addr 0xffffff7f89906000, size 49152)
loaded kexts:
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetAdp  6.1.4
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetFlt  6.1.4
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxUSB 6.1.4
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxDrv 6.1.4
@kext.AMDRadeonX6000    3.1.0
@kext.AMDRadeonServiceManager   3.1.0
>!AGraphicsDevicePolicy 5.2.6
@AGDCPluginDisplayMetrics   5.2.6
@fileutil   20.036.15
>!AHV   1
|IOUserEthernet 1.0.1
|IO!BSerialManager  7.0.6f7
>pmtelemetry    1
>!AUpstreamUserClient   3.6.8
>AGPM   111.4.4
>!APlatformEnabler  2.7.0d0
>X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
@Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X    7.0.0
>!A!IKBLGraphics    14.0.7
>AGDCBacklightControl   5.2.6
>!AThunderboltIP    3.1.4
>ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin    1.0.0
>BridgeAudioCommunication   6.70.7
>!ABacklight    180.3
>!AHIDALSService    1
>!A!ISlowAdaptiveClocking   4.0.0
>!ATopCaseHIDEventDriver    3430.1
>!AMuxControl2  5.2.6
>!AAVEBridge    6.1
>!ABridgeAudio!C    6.70.7
>!AGFXHDA   100.1.429
>!A!ICFLGraphicsFramebuffer 14.0.7
>!AFIVRDriver   4.1.0
>!AMCCSControl  1.14
>!A!IPCHPMC 2.0.1
@filesystems.autofs 3.0
>BCMWLANFirmware4355.Hashstore  1
>BCMWLANFirmware4364.Hashstore  1
>BCMWLANFirmware4377.Hashstore  1
>!ABCMWLANBusInterfacePCIe  1
>!AFileSystemDriver 3.0.1
@filesystems.hfs.kext   522.100.5
@BootCache  40
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeDataless    1.0.0d1
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeZlib    1.0.0
>!AVirtIO   1.0
@filesystems.apfs   1412.141.1
@private.KextAudit  1.0
>!ASmartBatteryManager  161.0.0
>!AACPIButtons  6.1
>!ASMBIOS   2.1
>!AACPIEC   6.1
>!AAPIC 1.7
$!AImage4   1
@nke.applicationfirewall    303
$TMSafetyNet    8
@!ASystemPolicy 2.0.0
|EndpointSecurity   1
>!AThunderboltPCIUpAdapter  2.5.4
@kext.AMDRadeonX6100HWLibs  1.0
@kext.AMDRadeonX6000HWServices  3.1.0
|IOUSBUserClient    900.4.2
|IOAVB!F    850.1
@!AGPUWrangler  5.2.6
>IOPlatformPluginLegacy 1.0.0
>!AHDA!C    283.15
|IOHDA!F    283.15
@kext.AMDRadeonX6000Framebuffer 3.1.0
>!ABacklightExpert  1.1.0
>!AActuatorDriver   3440.1
>!AHIDKeyboard  209
|IOSlowAdaptiveClocking!F   1.0.0
>!AHS!BDriver   3430.1
>IO!BHIDDriver  7.0.6f7
>!AMultitouchDriver 3440.1
>!AInputDeviceSupport   3440.8
>!AThunderboltEDMSink   4.2.3
>!AThunderboltDPOutAdapter  6.2.6
>!AGraphicsControl  5.2.6
>X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
|IONDRVSupport  576.1
>!ASMBusPCI 1.0.14d1
|IO!BHost!CUARTTransport    7.0.6f7
|IO!BHost!CTransport    7.0.6f7
>!A!ILpssUARTv1 3.0.60
>!A!ILpssUARTCommon 3.0.60
>!AOnboardSerial    1.0
@kext.AMDSupport    3.1.0
@!AGraphicsDeviceControl    5.2.6
|IOAccelerator!F2   438.7.3
>!ASMBus!C  1.0.18d1
|IOGraphics!F   576.1
>IOPlatformPlugin!F 6.0.0d8
@plugin.IOgPTPPlugin    840.3
|IOEthernetAVB!C    1.1.0
@kext.triggers  1.0
>usb.IOUSBHostHIDDevice 1.2
>usb.cdc.ecm    5.0.0
>usb.cdc.ncm    5.0.0
>usb.cdc    5.0.0
>usb.networking 5.0.0
>usb.!UHostCompositeDevice  1.2
>!ABCMWLANCore  1.0.0
>mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
>IOImageLoader  1.0.0
|IO80211!FV2    1200.12.2b1
>corecapture    1.0.4
|IOSkywalk!F    1
|IOSurface  269.11
@filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext 1
|IOAudio!F  300.2
@vecLib.kext    1.2.0
|IOSerial!F 11
>!AXsanScheme   3
>usb.!UVHCIBCE  1.2
>usb.!UVHCI 1.2
>usb.!UVHCICommonBCE    1.0
>usb.!UVHCICommon   1.0
>!AEffaceableNOR    1.0
|IOBufferCopy!C 1.1.0
|IOBufferCopyEngine!F   1
|IONVMe!F   2.1.0
>!AThunderboltPCIDownAdapter    2.5.4
>!AThunderboltDPInAdapter   6.2.6
>!AThunderboltDPAdapter!F   6.2.6
>!AHPM  3.4.4
>!A!ILpssI2C!C  3.0.60
>!A!ILpssDmac   3.0.60
>!A!ILpssI2C    3.0.60
>!AThunderboltNHI   5.8.6
|IOThunderbolt!F    7.6.1
>usb.!UHostPacketFilter 1.0
|IOUSB!F    900.4.2
>usb.!UXHCIPCI  1.2
>usb.!UXHCI 1.2
>!AEFINVRAM 2.1
>!AEFIRuntime   2.1
>!ASMCRTC   1.0
|IOSMBus!F  1.1
|IOHID!F    2.0.0
$quarantine 4
$sandbox    300.0
@kext.!AMatch   1.0.0d1
>!AKeyStore 2
>!UTDM  489.120.1
|IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice  422.120.3
>!ACredentialManager    1.0
>!AFDEKeyStore  28.30
>!AEffaceable!S 1.0
>!AMobileFileIntegrity  1.0.5
@kext.CoreTrust 1
|CoreAnalytics!F    1
|IOTimeSync!F   840.3
|IONetworking!F 3.4
>DiskImages 493.0.0
|IO!B!F 7.0.6f7
|IO!BPacketLogger   7.0.6f7
>!ASSE  1.0
>KernelRelayHost    1
>!ASEPManager   1.0.1
>IOSlaveProcessor   1
|IOUSBMass!SDriver  157.140.1
|IOSCSIArchitectureModel!F  422.120.3
|IO!S!F 2.1
|IOUSBHost!F    1.2
>usb.!UCommon   1.0
>!UHostMergeProperties  1.2
>!ABusPower!C   1.0
|IOReport!F 47
>!AACPIPlatform 6.1
>!ASMC  3.1.9
>watchdog   1
|IOPCI!F    2.9
|IOACPI!F   1.4
@kec.pthread    1
@kec.corecrypto 1.0
@kec.Libm   1
```

Is there anything I might be able to try before I try and call LG support for a repair?
Thanks!

Comment: Did you try a different port on your MacBook?

Comment: Yes, tried all four. I have now also tried a 15 inch MacBook and a windows device, will update the post with this info.